# $http - post - Bad request error not handled (undefined)

Tags: angularjs, http, post

I am trying to do a POST to create an account and I am expecting a 400 Bad Request (Username already used or Email already used).

I have confirmed with other tools (RESTED for firefox) that I am receiving the correct 400 Error with my message, but with AngularJS response.status, response.data and response.statusText all give an 'undefined' value.

Below is the definition of my request in AngularJS:

```
var req = {
              method: 'POST',
              url: myURL,
              headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Accept': 'application/json'
                      },
              data: $scope.user
            };

$http(req).then(
    function(response){
      console.log("account created perfectly!");
                      },
    function(response){
      console.log("ERROR " + response.status + ": account cannot be created!");
      // the data is Username/Password
      alert(response.data + " invalid!");
      }

    )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you send your final url you are sending to server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your inspector screenshot here?
Looks like there is some issue with the passing of request body.
The 4xx error comes when the client sends a bad request.

Also, for your use case, return status code 2xx as this is the valid business case and it should not be 4xX.

Comment: Using the inspector, I tried to display the response, and it was the error:
Error: $http:baddata Bad JSON Data.

I just needed to fix it in the back-end and everything was fine! I am getting my 400 Bad Request. By the way, I just don't know why he is not handling a simple string. If anyone knows...

Comment: Can you please post a plunkr or jsfiddle so that I can investigate the issue.

Comment: @AAA97AAA can you please post an answer detailing what you did to fix this issue? The answer you have accepted does not answer the question.